# How can I make a TCP-IP communication between 2 Visual C# apps?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, tcp

I just need to know how can I send a message from a server to a client, if the communication could be bidirectional it would be perfect, but it is not necessary.

Comment: [Search about C# client server tutorials](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sa=X&ei=l7A5TqiCE8PBswbzvbn-Dw&sqi=2&ved=0CBcQvwUoAQ&q=C%23+client+server+tutorials&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=5ebc4d519a3bd440&biw=1024&bih=677)

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2005/.NET 2.0 try [**.NET Remoting**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

**Edit**

Unless you enjoy the exercise I would advise against sockets.  .NET Remoting allows for TCP, UDP, IPC communication and to your code it just looks like you are calling a method/property on an object.  Also, any data structure that is serializable can be passed over the wire which lets you use rich data representation, rather than packaging/parsing byte streams at the socket level.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to use Sockets to accomplish this.  A good reference for this is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx

It has little overhead and can be configured much more simply than Remoting or other types of communication.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using .net remoting over tcp/ip.  This makes bi-directional communication a breeze.  You'll need a [TcpServerChannel](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.tcp.tcpserverchannel.aspx&ei=DbA5TtS0OZShsQKxtsEe&usg=AFQjCNGrhOsqMaZFGPnOyJM_2_bSQTtBcQ) on one side, a [TcpClientChannel](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.tcp.tcpclientchannel.aspx&ei=H7A5TqPlILOpsAKkuskR&usg=AFQjCNF_E-5AzPw3tCa36RheArGllZIP4Q) on the other side.  The server side will have an object that extends [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx).

```
public class MyServerClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
   public override void InitializeLifetimeService ()
   {
      return null;
   }

   public string SendAndRecieve (string message)
   {
      return message + message;
   }
}
```

Comment: Remoting is considered a "legacy" technology. The current replacement is WCF, which is easier to use, even more performant, and adheres to industry standards such as HTTP and SOAP.

Comment: yes it is, however, he states he is using VS 2005 and I am guessing .NET 2.0 as well, so is in a sense, developing a legacy app

Answer (score 0):

1. [WCF nettcpbinding](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article704-using-nettcpbinding-in-wcf-.aspx) from .net 3.5 [.Net Remouting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx) for .net 2
2. [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
3. [Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)

Try to google for examples, there are many examples with this

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the System.Messaging namespace and exchange messages over MSMQ.  Not sure of your requirements, so that may not be the best approach, but it is another way to quickly get messages between 2 .Net processes.